# Defining Variable

Tags: python, file

I have the program where I am grabbing the latest file from the folder.

```
def getList():
    previousFile = ''
    Files = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\kshah2\\Desktop\\MDR\\*")
    LatestFile = max(Files, key =os.path.getctime)
    if previousFile == '':
        previousFile = LatestFile
    if LatestFile != previousFile:
        File = open(LatestFile, "r")
        asc_list = [line for line in File.readlines()]
        event.source.parent.getComponent('Text Area').text = (system.file.readFileAsString(LatestFile))
        event.source.parent.getComponent('Label 1').text = str(LatestFile)
        event.source.running = 0
        event.source.value = 0
        previousFile = LatestFile
        File.close()
        return asc_list
    else:
        messageBox("Its Already used")
    return ''
```

The problem is, if I leave it like this, every time the function is called the previousFile will be erased which means it will grab the latestfile regardless it is executed or not.

But at the same time, if I don't have that first 2 lines then I throws me an error that the previousFile is not defined.

Where should I declare the previousFile? And how should I assign the LatestFile name to previousFile?
I know it should be something pretty simple but just can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not well described, but from my understanding a solution will require you to save 'previousFile' as a global variable.

```
class FileManage:
    def __init__(self):
        self._previousFile = ''

    def listSaver(self):
        for i in NumberOfFiles:
            self.getList()  

    def getList(self):
        # Use the global self._previousFile.
```

the self._previousFile is saved after itertaion and is initialize once in the begining.

If you're having a hard time understanding classes, you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Ok, got it. Editing my answer.